# How to set auto column width for datatable in R Shiny Report

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I'm unable to set auto column width in a data table which is part of a shiny dashboard.

It appears in more than one line like ("Apr-" in one line and "18" in another line; Similarly "Banking" in one line and "Products" in another line)

[image]

[image]

I'm using the below script but not working.

Can anyone please help me to solve this?

```
output$Tabledt = DT::renderDataTable({datatable(table1(), rownames = FALSE, plugins = "ellipsis", options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = c(1))))) %>%
          formatRound(columns = c(2:73), digits = 2)
          })
    }
```

Have given below an example as requested.

Dataframe:

```
TableA = data.frame('Description' = c('Marketing & Communications', 'Corp Development & Strategy', 'COG Technology Workplace'), 'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3),'Test Lengthy Column header' = c(1:3))
```

Server:

```
server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$Tabledt = DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(TableA[], rownames = FALSE, plugins = "ellipsis",
              options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = c(1))))) %>%
      formatRound(columns = c(2), digits = 2)
  })
  
    output$mainpanel = renderUI({tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Report", value = 'tab1', DT::dataTableOutput("Tabledt")))})

}
```

UI:

```
library(shiny)
ui = shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    mainPanel(uiOutput("mainpanel"))
  )
)
```

App:

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the above example, somehow the value column headers are auto fitted but not the first column. In my real world scenario all the column widths are not getting auto adjusted. Don't know why.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added an example.

Comment: Try adding class = "nowrap" to your datatable()